# mod_rewrite messing up the site navigation links

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache

On my main page, the navigation links are as follows:

- localhost/inventory/add
- localhost/inventory/view

The code for those are:

```
<a href='add'>Add Record</a>
<a href='view'>View Records</a>
```

and my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ./index.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([^/\.]+)/?$ ./index.php?url=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The problem I am having is that for the records, there is an edit link that takes them to:

- localhost/inventory/edit/1

For record one, and the code for that link is:

```
<a href='edit/1'>Edit</a>
```

Which is fine, except now the navigation links take them to:

- localhost/inventory/edit/add
- localhost/inventory/edit/view

Because it thinks it is in an 'edit' directory.

Does anyone know of an idea to overcome this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably not because `.htaccess`, but the difference between relative versus absolute links. That is to say your navigation links should probably be prefixed with `/`, like:

```
<a href='/inventory/add'>Add Record</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Jason, putting the / makes the link relative to the server root.  I guess I could have a config file and any subdirectory the script is running in would need to be assigned, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry. This is web urls 101. If the link is simply `add` it's always going to be relative to the current directory. I don't think you're going to have much luck creating a rewrite rule that gets around that.

Comment: OK thank you, that wasn't the answer I was hoping for but its the answer I was unfortunately anticipating.

Comment: Sorry. Again, not impossible, but don't think you'd have much luck. That's why most frameworks include rewrite rules and their own link generation functions. Instead of just rewrite rules.